# chacha20-poly1305 padding and length encoding

Tags: mac, stream-cipher, poly1305, chacha

The AEAD construction for chacha20-poly1305 described in the [IETF proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-agl-tls-chacha20poly1305-01#page-7) encodes message lengths into the text that is to be hashed. The [newer proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-chacha20-poly1305-08#page-18) goes further and pads associated data and plaintext to multiples of 16 bytes.

Can anyone explain what the purpose of that is? The chacha20-poly1305 implementation found in OpenSSH doesn't do anything like that, and as far as I can see, neither does NaCl. Those are still considered secure so I wonder what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the padding (and re-positioning of the AAD length) in the later draft is to make implementations easier and faster - i.e. not for a security reason.

The rationale for this change was actually documented on the [CFRG mailing list](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/cfrg/u734TEOSDDWyQgE0pmhxjdncwvw) by Alyssa Rowan:

> Instead of the lengths directly following their ciphertexts:
>
> draft-agl-tls-chacha20poly1305-04:
>
> ```
>   AAD | len_AAD | ciphertext | len_ciphertext
> ```
>
> this final version of the AEAD pads the Additional Authenticated Data
>   (if any) and ciphertext to a 16-byte block boundary (using between
>   0-15 zero bytes) and moves the lengths to the end:
>
> draft-nir-cfrg-chacha20-poly1305 (the final AEAD specified here):
>
> ```
>   AAD | padding1 | ciphertext | padding2 | len_AAD | len_ciphertext
> ```
>
> which is more efficient to implement (block-aligned, and the recipient
>   knows the lengths are at the end, instead of having to jump backwards
>   to find len_AAD). Thanks to Niels Moeller for that idea.

Comment: I'm confused by this part: "the recipient knows the lengths are at the end, instead of having to jump backwards to find len_AAD". If I understand correctly, this is describing the input to the MAC, which is something the recipient needs to _recreate_ rather than something they'd ever want to parse. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that makes obvious sense either - the lengths are computed on both encrypt and decrypt in the abstract specification. I'd speculate there's a desire to have a packet format identical to the AEAD structure here, in which case the comment would make more sense.